# Spring boot batch job identification

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-configuration

I have tried to find the answer for seemingly simple but the evasive question. How does spring identify jobs in the batch configuration. Everything is annotated with @Bean and nothing to identify. Does the spring identify those with keywords in the name itself? Like xyzStep xzyJob etc? I'm trying to follow the official documentation at [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything is annotated with @Bean and nothing to identify. Does the spring identify those with keywords in the name itself?

Yes, as documented in the [Javadoc of the `@Bean` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html):

```
the default strategy for determining the name of a bean is to use the name of the @Bean method
```

That said, it should be noted that there is a difference between the Spring bean name and the Spring Batch job/step name (those can be different):

```
@Bean
public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
            //...
            .build();
}
```

In this example, the Spring bean name is `job` and the Spring Batch job name is `myJob`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring identifies the job on the event when we try starting the job. Below is a small snippet for reference,

This is a bean definition which returns of type Job and contains all the orchestration of steps in it,

```
  @Bean
  public Job testJob() throws Exception {

    Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("testJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(step1()).next(step2()).next(step3()).end()
        .listener(jobCompletionListener()).build();

    ReferenceJobFactory referenceJobFactory = new ReferenceJobFactory(job);
    registry.register(referenceJobFactory);

    return job;
}
```

Below would make use of the bean and start the job which means that the workflow defined as a part of job would get executed,

```
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
Job testJob;

// eliminating the method defnition for simplicity,

  try {
        jobLauncher.run(testJob, jobParameters);
  } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception while running a batch job {}", e.getMessage());
  }
```